# Printing month and date using python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to print only the month and date in python as following :

```
09-December
08-October
```

How could I do that?

Comment: A good start would be writing some code. Please show us what you have attempted so far, and explain the problem that you are having with it.

Comment: Read this: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print now.strftime("%d-%B")
```

For more information on this : [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime("09/12/16", "%d/%m/%y")
dt.strftime("%d-%B")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import date

d = date(2016, 12, 9)
d.strftime("%d - %A")
# 9 - Friday
# month day year
#d.strftime("%A %d %B %Y")
```