# Python convert date format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-3.7

Given a string like this:

```
2020-08-14
```

How do I convert it to:

```
14 August 2020
```

Using python 3?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41055956/

Comment: Read up on [datetime — Basic date and time types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach using pandas function below:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.to_datetime('2020-08-14')
d.strftime('%d %B %Y')
Out[11]: '14 August 2020'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `datetime` module for reformatting date strings. Using `strptime` you can read from a string into a `datetime` object, then using `strftime` you can convert back to a string with a different format.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.strptime('2020-08-14', '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 0, 0)
>>> d.strftime('%d %B %Y')
'14 August 2020'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
monthDict = {
'01' : 'January',
'02' : 'February',
'03' : 'March',
'04' : 'April',
'05' : 'May',
'06' : 'June',
'07' : 'July',
'08' : 'August',
'09' : 'September',
'10' : 'October',
'11' : 'November',
'12' : 'December'
}
readDate = input('Pleaes enter the date in the yyyy-mm-dd format: ')
day = readDate.split('-')[2]
month = readDate.split('-')[1]
year = readDate.split('-')[0]
print('Printing in the dd month year format: ', day, monthDict[month], year)
```